# Calling a method from layout xml with DialogFragment.. how does that work?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

Let's say I have this button:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/idone"
android:layout_width="0dip"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="D2"
android:onClick="myMeth"/>
```

I have several times used this to call methods from a layout xml as it calls the method from the activity that inflated such view.

Recently with DialogFragments, well it does not work at all.  I keep getting an error telling me that such method does not exist.  Where is it then looking for such method? I have added it to the DialogFragment class:

```
public class myActivity extends DialogFragment {

public DiceDialog() {
    // empty constructor
}

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myDialog, container);
        getDialog().setTitle("Hello");
        return view;
    }

public void myMeth(View view) {
//...
    }
```

As well as in the activity that instantiates the FragmentManager and calls the dialog:

```
public Class MainActiviry Extends  FragmentActivity {

//...
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// ..
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
MyActivity dialog = new AddDiceDialog();
dialog.show(fm, "tag");
}

public void myMeth(View view){
//...
}
```

And still the messag is that MyMeth is not found.

I have already [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867425/communication-between-fragments-dialogs-in-android) that using interfaces and listeners is the correct way to communicate between activity and dialog fragments, but what I am trying to figure out here is where that myMeth call is being made, because well,it is called.

Comment: XML is still inflated by your activity. And I guess layout inflater will look for that method where it was inflated, Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `public myMeth(View view)` in your `Activity`, which will then check for the currently visible `Fragment`, and call its method.

If you want to use more then one callable method in your `Fragment`, you can utilize the id's of the calling views and implement a `switch`, calling a different fragment method according to the id of the `View`.

Comment: With this you mean that MyMeth will be looked up in the activity? Because I have added it and it still doesn't find it

Comment: yes, myMeth will be called in the activity, but you must have it defined as such: "public void myMeth(View view)"

Comment: I still get the same error message, have you tried this yourself? I edited my question now

Comment: notice what I've said earlier, you must define it as "public void myMeth(View view)" - not as  "public myMeth()"