# Refreshing a ListAdapter from a Dialog

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog, listadapter

I pretty stumped on how to refresh a ListAdapter I have in an activity from an AlertDialog I'm calling from the same activity.

Here's the code of the activity:

```
private static ArrayAdapter<CarProfile> mainListAdapter;

public class CarProfiles : ListActivity
{
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        mainListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CarProfile>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, carProfiles);
        // This targets a ListView in my axml with id list.
        ListAdapter = mainListAdapter;

        ShowCarProfileFormDialog(parameters blah, blah, blah);
    }
}
```

And this is my AlertDialog:

```
    public class CarProfileDialogFragment : DialogFragment
    {
        public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = Activity.LayoutInflater;
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.CarProfileForm, null);

            // component init (removed)

            var builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Activity)
                .SetView(view)
                .SetPositiveButton(GetString(Resource.String.lblCarProfileDialogOK), (sender, args) =>
                {        
                    // The datasouce source update works
                    datasource.UpdateCarProfile(id, txtName.Text, txtPlateNumber.Text, spnCategoryColor.SelectedItem.ToString(), spnCategoryNumber.SelectedItem.ToString());

                    // But this doesn't 
                    mainListAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();                        
                })
                .SetNegativeButton(GetString(Resource.String.lblCarProfileDialogCancel), (sender, args) =>
                {
                    Dialog.Dismiss();
                })
                .SetTitle(GetString(Resource.String.lblCarProfileDialogTitle));
            return builder.Create();
        }
    }
```

Shown in the AlertDialog code above, my datasouce get updated with no problems and when I call the `NotifyDataSetChanged` method nothing happens.

Comment: Does that ever compile ? There are a couple of java synxtax errors in this file.

Comment: This is monodroid. I don't mind a Java solution though.

Comment: I can't say for MonoDroid, but in normal Java you should use an event based mechanism to allow your fragment to communicate with your activity, that will then refresh the list.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867425/communication-between-fragments-dialogs-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I scrapped this approach and copied the NotepadV3 example instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because `NotifyDataSetChanged()` is just a method to let the adapter to redraw the view but doesn't change the underlying data, you need to let `mainListAdapter` know the new data by calling either something like `mainListAdapter.Clear()`, `mainListAdapter.Add()` to **update** the data or `ArrayAdapter`'s constructor again.