# Android, NavigationComponent, communication between fragments

Tags: android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I'm working on ongoing project which uses Android NavigationComponent and having trouble on figuring out how to get result back from fragment I displayed. 
If I would display fragment with FragmentTransaction I use this aproach [Android - getTargetFragment and setTargetFragment - What are they used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561119/android-gettargetfragment-and-settargetfragment-what-are-they-used-for)