# How to correclty return a variable from a Fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-navigation

Situation:

[image]

1. At first fragment on button press I want to open second fragment with
   sections
2. On second fragment I can create new section(or use existed) then on list item
   click open third fragment
3. On third fragment I can write new service(or use existed) and then on button
   click return to first fragment
4. and display Section(from second fragment) and Service(from third
   fragment)

   - My idea is to use `fragment.setArguments(bundle)` on second fragment and transfer it to third fragment
   - On third fragment with `interface A{public void sendData(data);}` I will return variable to fragment one

How I should correctly return variables From AllServicesSectionFragmnet + AllServicecDescriptionFragment to CreateNewServiceFragment?

Comment: How are you returning from Fragment 3 to Fragment 1?

Answer (score 0):

give Tag to fragmentA

`fragmentTransaction.add(new FragmentA(),"frag_Tag")`

and in third fragment add

`FragmentA fback=FragmentManager.findfragmentByTag("frag_Tag")`

and write in backButton method

`if(fback!=null)
{
 fback.show;
}`

Comment: This contain SecondFragment not FirstFragment   `FragmentA fback=FragmentManager.findfragmentByTag("frag_Tag")`

Comment: This tag for fragmentA ,FragmentB have different Tag

Answer (score 0):

You can treat your Fragment as a function: it can be invoked from another Fragment and can return a value (using [setTargetFragment and onActivityResult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45612863/3050249)).

When you want another Fragment to give you a value, you invoke it with setTargetFragment and wait for onActivityResult to be called. When invoked fragment opens another Fragment to get its task done, it also should wait for onActivityResult and return a value to caller.

So, pseudocode:

```
fn fragment1() {
    handleData(call fragment2(arg));
}

fn fragment2(arg: T) -> U {
    return handle(call fragment3(arg));
}

fn fragment3(arg: T) -> U {
    // handle some user input
    return value;
}
```

can be represented as series of setTargetFragment and onActivityResult invocations.