# AlertDialog Listener not attached

Tags: kotlin, android-alertdialog

MyAlertDialog throws ClassCastException when trying to set the context to the listener. I'm calling the MyAlertDailog from a fragment.

I'm using the guide found in the android dev docs.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#PassingEvents

MyFragment

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(), MyAlerDialog.MyAlertDialogListener {

    ...

    fun launchAlertDialog() {
        val dailog = MyAlertDialog().also {
            it.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "DialogInfoFragment")
        } 
    }

    override fun onDialogPostiveCLick(dialog: DialogFragment) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Listener returns a postive click")
    }
}
```

MyAlertDialog

```
class MyAlertDialog : DialogFragment() {
    
    // Use thsi instance for the interface
    internal var listener: MyAlertDialogListener

    // My Fragment implements this interface. 
    interface MyAlertDialogListener {
        onDialogPositiveClick(dialog: DialogFragment)
    }

   
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        // Verify  that the host implements the callback. 
        try {
            // My problem is here. 
            listener = context as MyAlertDailog
        } catch (e: ClassCastException) {
            // exception thrown here. 
            throw ClassCastException((context.toString() + " must implement MyAlertDailogListener")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState:Bundle?): Dialog {
        return activity?.let {
             val builder = AlertDialog.builder(it)
             ...
             builder.setPosiviveButton("Positive button",
               DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
                   listener.onDialogPositiveClick(this)     
             }
        }
    }

}
```

Error report

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.androiddevpractice.MainActivity@ab56136 must implement MyAlertDialogListener
        at com.example.androiddevpractice.topics.userinterface.dialog.MyAlertDialog.onAttach(MyAlertDialog.kt:35)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the `launchAlertDialog()` method is inside of `MyFragment`, the "host" for `MyAlertDialog` is your **Activity**, not `MyFragment`.

Implement `MyAlerDialog.MyAlertDialogListener` inside of `MainActivity` in order for the cast to succeed. MainActivity can then communicate to `MyFragment` if it has to.

---

Alternatively, you could use [`setTargetFragment()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32323822/8298909) in order to "connect" MyFragment and MyAlertDialog directly:

```
val dialog = MyAlertDialog()
dialog.setTargetFragment(this, 0)
dialog.show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "DialogInfoFragment")
```

Then, rather than overriding `onAttach()` and casting a context, you would cast the results of `getTargetFragment()`:

```
builder.setPosiviveButton(
        "Positive button",
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
            val listener = targetFragment as MyAlertDialogListener
            listener.onDialogPositiveClick(this)     
        }
)
```