# How can I change the textView of an Activity from a DialogFragment?

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

This is the java file of the activity

```
private TextView tv;

 private Button btn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_agente);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Estado);
    }

    //Método para el bottón rojo

    protected void BotonRojo(View view){
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DialogoOcupado();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Un Dialogo");
    }


Thats the DialogFragment class(extends DialogFragment)


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle("Aviso")
                .setMessage("Vas a pasar a estado Ocupado, estás seguro?")
                .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                })
                .setNeutralButton("Más Tarde", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }
```

I want to change the `TextView(tv)` when the user press the button "Aceptar". How can I do it? I'm learning programming Android sorry.

Comment: Use interface or local broadcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There can be many ways to do this. *Simplest I think is this...*

Create a method in your `Activity`. and call it from `Dialog`.

```
((YourActivity)getActivity()).changeStatus("pass anything");
```

make `changeStatus()` method in your `Activity`.

```
public void changeStatus(String s){
   tv.setText(s);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but What's the name of my activity? Can I just put the name there or must I pass the value from the activity to the DialogFragment?

Comment: It is called type casting in java. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/5289493/6891563

Comment: You will just write name of your activity and import that.

Comment: But this will cause class cast exception if he uses same dialog fragment from another activity

Comment: If you need to do this from multiple source, then you will use interface.

Comment: See this perfectly match your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/10867597/6891563

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
public void changeText(String text){
    textView.setText(text);
}
```

from dialog fragment ,

```
((Your activity)getActivity()).changeText(text);
```

Comment: Sorry for being a noob, but What's the name of my activity? Can I just put the name there or must I pass the value from the activity to the DialogFragment?